# Clear text input after submit

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Here I am adding new column to my data frame. 
The below code is working good. After added a new column, the texts inside the "Variable name" and "Formula" should be empty.

Could you please help me.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel( "", ""),
  sidebarPanel(

    wellPanel(

      fileInput('file', 'Select csv file', accept=c('text/csv') ),

      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),

      gsub("label class=\"radio\"", "label class=\"radio inline\"",
           radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';', Tab='\t' )))

    ),

    wellPanel(
      checkboxInput('addcol', 'Create New Variable', FALSE),

      conditionalPanel(condition="input.addcol!=0",
                       textInput('newvar', "Variable name","" ),
                       textInput('newformula', "Formula",""),
                       actionButton("addvar","Apply"))      
    )
    ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(tableOutput('contents'))
    )
  )

))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  dataset = reactive({
    inFile<-input$file
    if(is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
  })


  alterdata = reactive({
    if(input$addcol!=0&&input$addvar!=0){
      isolate({
        df<-dataset()
        df$Var1<-eval(parse(text=input$newformula), df)
        df<-rename(df, c(Var1=input$newvar))
        df
      })
    }
    else
    {
      dataset()
    }
  })

  output$contents<-renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$file)) { return() }                            
    alterdata()
  })

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using `updateTextInput().` Here's the [help on that function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/updateTextInput).

Here's what the updated server.R will look like:

**Modified Server.R**

Note that two lines have been added to the alterdata() reactive function.

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  dataset = reactive({
    inFile<-input$file
    if(is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
  })


  alterdata = reactive({
    if(input$addcol!=0&&input$addvar!=0){
      isolate({
        df<-dataset()
        df$Var1<-eval(parse(text=input$newformula), df)
        df<-rename(df, c(Var1=input$newvar))

        #add these two lines
        updateTextInput(session, "newvar", value = " ")     
        updateTextInput(session, "newformula", value = " ")     

        df        
      })
    }
    else
    {
      dataset()
    }
  })


  output$contents<-renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$file)) { return() }                            
    alterdata()    
  })

})
```

Note that I had to include `plyr` so that `rename` could be invoked.

Comment: Thanks... It's worked. You added clearText reactive function, I think it's not required. And also I added reshape instead of plyr, it is working..

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by Deans shinyjs package here.https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/reset.html